# How do you derive an expression for the output voltage of a ladder network of N sections?

Tags: passive-networks

I am really stuck with a result from a circuit lecture slide. I understand how the thevenin equivalent circuit for this section shows the general result. But I am stuck on how to prove it generally for N sections.

[image]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try induction. You can see that the Thevenin equivalent is the same as the left part of the original circuit, except the voltage. So every additional step will follow the same derivation. So you can easily express step number `N+1` in terms of the Thevenin equivalent of  `N` steps

Comment: Generating functions are used to solve recurrences. What you have is a recurrence relation. You can solve it directly. But it may be more interesting to apply the methods of generating functions, too. Anyway, what exactly are you looking to achieve? It's the case that \$R_i=\frac{2 R\left(R+R_{i-1}\right)}{3R+R_{i-1}}\$, where \$R_{i-1}\$ is the prior equivalent source impedance leading up to section \$i\$. It seems easy to see that this is bounded: \$\frac23R\le R_i\le2R\$. So I'm left not really knowing how you want this chased down. I understand induction may not be satisfying.

Comment: @jonk *I understand induction may not be satisfying* - Why? Induction, when possible is the most satisfying proof technique I can think of :) And here it is asking for it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I saw instantly what you saw. But it's not always the most satisfying. Partly because many aren't comfortable with propositional calculus and are much more comfortable with a geometric or algebraic proof. Inductive rigor comes first from Dedekind and Peano and natural numbers, memory serving. In any case, I just don't know what the OP wants. So I'm asking.

Comment: @jonk I am trying to see how my lecturer got to the equation for the output voltage V/2^N. I am just really stuck on how they got this result. When I try reducing the circuit by combining resistors in parallel, I don't see a kind of general pattern.

Comment: @BorisvanGriensven I thought you said you wanted to know about the resistance development. But you instead want the voltage?

Comment: @jonk yep exactly, I am confused about how much lecturer derived the formula for Vout in terms of Vin using thevenin. I am not sure whether he is applying  Thevenin to the "first section" which includes the non-ideal voltage source, or just the repeated section

Comment: @jonk When I apply thevenin to the first section I get a resistance of 2 ohms, because I add the two 1 ohhm resistors together, because I think the 2ohm resistor is the load resistor.

Answer (score 2):

By inspection, adding a further \$\small 1 \:\Omega /2\: \Omega\$ stage always results in the same Thevenin resistance, but half the Thevenin voltage, of the preceding stage. So the output resistance never changes, and the Thevenin voltage source halves each time a stage is added; hence, for the \$\small N'th\$ stage the voltage is \$\frac{10}{2^N}\$

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRlMIL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's the case that \$R_i=\frac{2R\left(R+R_{i-1}\right)}{3R+R_{i-1}}\$, where \$R_{i-1}\$ is the prior source impedance leading up to section \$i\$. It seems easy to see that this is bounded such that: \$\frac23R\le R_i\le2R\$.

It's also the case that \$V_i=V_{i-1}\frac{2R}{3R+R_{i-1}}\$, where \$V_{i-1}\$ is the prior ideal voltage source leading up to section \$i\$. It seems easy to see that this is bounded such that: \$0\:\text{V}\le V_i\le\frac23V_{i-1}\$.

$$\begin{align*}
R_0 &= R & V_0&=V\\\\
R_1 &= \frac{2R\left(R+R_{i-1}\right)}{3R+R_{i-1}}=R & V_1&=V_{i-1}\frac{2R}{3R+R_{i-1}}=\frac12V\\\\
R_2 &= \frac{2R\left(R+R_{i-1}\right)}{3R+R_{i-1}}=R & V_2&=V_{i-1}\frac{2R}{3R+R_{i-1}}=\frac14V\\\\
R_3 &= \dots & V_3&=\dots
\end{align*}$$

The above represents two recurrences: \$R_i\$ and \$V_i\$. The recurrence \$R_i\$ only depends upon itself. But the recurrence \$V_i\$ depends upon both itself as well as upon the recurrence \$R_i\$.

It's not terribly hard to prove the solution for the recurrence \$R_i\$ by induction, as Eugene suggested:

1. For \$i=0\$, it is the case that \$R_0=R\$. This is axiomatically true.
2. For any \$i\gt 0\$, the inductive hypothesis is that if you assume \$R_{i-1}=R\$ then \$R_{i}=\frac{2R\left(R+R_{i-1}\right)}{3R+R_{i-1}}=R\$.

   And therefore \$R_i=R_{i-1}\$.
3. For \$i=1\$ it is the case that the assumption of \$R_{i-1}=R\$, made in #2 above, is true (given #1 above.) Given that fact, it therefore also follows from #2 above that \$R_{i}=R\$.

   As \$R_0=R\$ and all \$R_i=R_{i-1}\$ for \$i\gt 0\$, the solution to this recurrence is that \$R_i=R\$ for all \$i\ge 0\$.

In the case of the voltage, it's more like this:

1. For \$i=0\$, it is the case that \$V_0=V\$. This is axiomatically true.
2. For any \$i\gt 0\$, the inductive hypothesis is that \$R_{i-1}=R\$ has already just proven so it follows that \$V_{i}=V_{i-1}\frac{2R}{3R+R_{i-1}}\$.

   And therefore \$V_i=\frac12 V_{i-1}\$.
3. For \$i=1\$ it is the case that the assumption of \$R_{i-1}=R\$, made in #2 above, is true (given #1 above.) Given that fact, it therefore also follows from #2 above that \$R_{i}=R\$.

I'm going to leave this here, for now, simply by way of extending on Eugene's comment and Chu's answer. (I may choose to come back and add more, illustrating it better via generating functions.)